# How can I print all the products attributes in product.html

Tags: django, django-templates

This is my models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    summary = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
```

This is my Django views.py

```
def products_view(request,*args, **kwargs):
    print(Product.objects.values())
    myDict = list()
    for product in Product.objects.all():
        my_product = {
        "product_id": product.id,
        "product_title":product.title,
        "product_description":product.description,
        "product_price":product.price,
        "product_summary":product.summary,
        "product_image":product.image
        }
        print(my_product)
    return render(request, "products.html", my_product)
```

This my products.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Products Page</h1>

<ul>
{% for product in my_product %}
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="{{ product_image }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ product_id }}">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{ product_title }}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">{{ product_description }}</p>
    <a href="/cart" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Basket</a>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

My Product.html page only show the "h1" tag, do not show the Products attributes. How can I achieve this problem? 
Products.objects.all() gives me QuerySet and I tried to change into dict. but I cannot print the dict elements' attributes .

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/

Comment: It show also your lack of knowledge of python itself  as you are overwriting your my_product  dict fields whole time

Answer (score 1):

Your view should send products through context

```
def products_view(request,*args, **kwargs):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'products': products } 
    return render(request, "products.html", context)
```

also in template then you can use

```
{% for product in products %}
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="{{ product.image.url}}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ product.id}}">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.title}}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">{{ product.description}}</p>
    <a href="/cart" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Basket</a>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop the loop in your view function and try something like this below.  There is no need to loop through each object in the view - your query has retrieved everything, and it's available to your template when you pass it through as context.  Use the template language to access each object's attribute.

```
def products_view(request,*args, **kwargs):

    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, "products.html", products)
```

And in your HTML, do something like:

```
{% for product in products %}

  {{product.title}}
  {{product.description}}
  {{product.price}}
  {{product.summary}}
  {{product.image}}

{% endfor %}
```

This HTML will render weird in my example, but you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `for loop` doesn't print out correctly is because `my_product` is not an iterable so the template cannot loop over it.

You will need to change this to be an iterable - like a list or queryset.

```
def products_view(request,*args, **kwargs):
    print(Product.objects.values())

    my_product = Product.objects.all()

    print(my_product)
    return render(request, "products.html", {'my_product': my_product})
```

Now, in the template, you will be able to access the product attributes using dot notation.

```
{% for product in my_product %}
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img src="{{ product.image }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ product.id }}">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.title }}</h5>
      <p class="card-text">{{ product.description }}</p>
      <a href="/cart" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Basket</a>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```